# kubernetes creates more pods than scale amount

Tags: kubernetes

I have encountered a  strange situation in one of our clusters, where all of a sudden a number of new pods have been created so that we end up with a greater number of running pods than the scale amount.

So in the dashboard it will show

> serviceX pods: 8/2

and then 8 running instances of that service

[image]

**Questions**

1. How can this possibly happen?
2. Is there an easy way to get rid
   of the extra pods (which all seem to be running)?

I have tried changing the scale amount in the dashboard and the extra pods do not disappear.

Comment: Did you described the deployment (`kubectl describe deploy ...`)  and checked the recent events? (This can give you some clues). There is any [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) configured for your deployments? If so, check its events as well.

Comment: Is all pods for an deployment managed by the same replicaset?

Comment: @Jonas yes they are

Comment: You might have `autoscaling` enabled. Check your cloud's provider which I think is GKE to configure that. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/scaling-apps

Answer (score 0):

Both Pod and [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) are full-fledged objects in the Kubernetes API. Deployment manages creating Pods by means of ReplicaSets. What it boils down to is that Deployment will create Pods with spec taken from the template.

In your case deployment name edgeservicepublic-svc is set to have 13 replicas. Deployment is a kind of controller in Kubernetes. Its is naturally that this controller with continuously check if 13 pods are created. When a deployment is added to the cluster, it will automatically spin up the requested number of pods, and then monitor them. If a pod dies, the deployment will automatically re-create it. Probably at first not enough pods are created co controller with pursue to achieve desried number of them.

To make sure your deployment works properly you can delete deployment, make sure that that pods are deleted. Make sure that you haven't set up [autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) ( `$ kubectl get hpa` ) if so, delete it.  Then if you want to change deployment specification edit deployment configuration file and apply changes  (`$ kubectl apply -f deployment_configuration_file.yaml`).

Useful documentation about [deployment](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/deployment) , [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/scaling-apps)  in context of GKE.

EDIT:

Basically at first place check autoscaler then delete it if it exists. I told you to delete deployment because you told that you try to change scale amount/ number of replicas. So if you want to be 100 % sure that changes are applied is to delete whole deployment end then recreate it with desired number of replicas. Of course you can just apply changes in deployment configuration file ($ kubectl edit ...) or ( $ kubectl apply -f ) but sometimes existing pods are not deleted so it will be saver. You could also create new deployment with the same parameters but different name.

Comment: The problem is that the deployments are not set to have that many replicas. For instance here is the yaml for the edgeservice deployment  "spec": {
    "replicas": 2,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "name": "edgeservicepublic-svc"
      }

Comment: Basically you are saying to delete everything and re-created it, hoping the issue will be resolved.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you tell me if it works ?